# Rotativa can't find ActionAsPdf: The type or namespace name 'ActionAsPdf' could not be found when using Rotativa.AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, rotativa

I'm using nuget package Rotativa.AspNetCore in my .NET 7.0 web application.

I'm trying to use the ActionAsPdf method to convert my View into PDF,

```
   public ActionResult PrintAllEmployee()
     {
         var report = new ActionAsPdf("Employees");
         return report;
     }
```

My problem is that *ActionAsPdf* is missing

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ActionAsPdf' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Only *ViewAsPdf* seems to be available, like if *ActionAsPdf* was not available in package *Rotativa.AspNetCore*

I've tried with another testing application, using Rotativa package, and there I can find *ActionAsPdf* but when I use it like this:

```
public ActionResult PrintAllEmployee()
    {
            var report = new ActionAsPdf("Employees");
            return report;
    }
```

I have the error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Rotativa.ActionAsPdf' to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'

I'd like to use the *ActionAsPdf* method from Rotativa.AspNetCore, if possible

Do you know how can I fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionAsPdf` is used in [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/tree/master) instead of [Rotativa.AspNetCore](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore). It supports in ASP.NET instead of ASP.NET Core.

You need use `ViewAsPdf` to print view as pdf.

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return new ViewAsPdf();
}
```

Comment: ViewAsPdf() only returns the View, I'm struggling to retrieve the data via my controller when using it, any idea?

Comment: Hi @Hakeem, the github repo contains such example, or you can check the answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/61864127/11398810  for how to pass the data to the view.

Comment: Thanks Rena, I've been able to sort this. Thank you for your help